# Scrapy HTTP Request error when trying to send request login on nike site

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, bots

I'm trying to make a sneaker bot for Nike sneakers brazil site (nike.com.br/snkrs) using scraping. First, I tried to make a spider that logs into the site, I see that have some login requests on the network so I tried to send the ones that I think are needed.

Here is the full code of the spider:

```
<https://pastebin.com/Xke6kP1P>
```

But when I tried to crawl the spider to test I get some http request errors like 400 Bad Request, 401 POST HTTP Request not handle or allowed or 403 Forbidden.
Here is the full error code:

```
<https://pastebin.com/ge9pr6qx>
```

I already using proxy ip and user agent rotation middlewares but still get these errors.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Please always post code and errors in text.

Answer (score 0):

One way to try to solve this problem is editing your `settings.py`.

You should copy headers that come with a response.
In order to achieve an access with success copy all this parameters from a default web browser.

Access the developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) `network tab`, do a navigation in site, copy information from some request in that domain.

***settings.py***

```
USER_AGENT = '' #copy user-agent from browser

# Override the default request headers:
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
  'Accept': '', #copy this info from browser
  'Accept-Language': '', #copy this info from browser
}
```

Here is a [good tutorial](http://sangaline.com/post/advanced-web-scraping-tutorial/) (2017) that explains in detail how can you handle navigation errors, old but you can get the main idea. This tutorial is also linked in scrapy web site `resources` section.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You get 403 forbidden because of your _abck cookie.

Comment: Please explain why.

Comment: basically this cookie tells if you are a bot based on the sensor data it gets from your user agent, mouse and keyboard events on the page and lots of other things.. so if akamai gives you a good cookie, you wont get 403